# How to download url file from firebase firestore flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I download a file from firebase firestore after I push the url from firebase storage to firebase firestore? I try to display the list of audio file. But how to download the file from firestore?

```
Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getAudioFile() async {
Map<String, dynamic> audios = {
  "audio": audio,
};

var docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Audio");
QuerySnapshot query = await docRef.limit(10).get();
return query.docs;
```

}

[image: Error when im using forEach]
[image]
[image: The output]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file you are trying to download is publicly readable, and if not you can read [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) to make it so, all you have to is use the URL to download the file as follows:

```
var docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Audio");
QuerySnapshot query = await docRef.limit(10).get();
query.forEach((doc) async {
    // this variable will contain your downloaded file and you can build your code from here
    http.Response downloadData = await http.get(doc.url);
});
```

Comment: when i code query.forEach, the forEach is error. why?

Comment: the forEach got the red line under the sentences

Comment: but what is the error message? Can you edited that into your question?

Comment: maybe the query did not return any results? try adding a condition before the foreach, something like: `if(query.size() > 0)`

Comment: hmm still the same

Comment: that is weird, what happens if you log the value of query? what comes up?

Comment: i cannot run the apps since the forEach statement is error

Comment: try commenting out the whole forEach and log the value of query, let's troubleshoot this.

Comment: ow too log since the forEach statement is error and cannot debug the application. Im sorry i know nothing :(

Comment: what do you mean with `too log since the forEach statement is error and cannot debug the application`?

Comment: im sorry.  Cannot show the log since the forEach statement is error like the picture above and cannot debug the application

Comment: like I said, if you comment out the entire foreach, you will be able to run... If you don't do this I won't be able to help you....

Comment: I already add the output in the question. I want to download when i try the download button but idk how to do it. im sorry for the complicated things